# "Inline declaration is not possible in this position" in a method parameter

Tags: methods, abap

The below code gives this error:

> The inline declaration "DATA(LV_DESKTOP)" is not possible in this position.

```
  CALL METHOD cl_gui_frontend_services=>get_desktop_directory
    CHANGING
      desktop_directory = data(lv_desktop). "Declaring in method
```

Comment: What error does it give, is it a syntax error or an error at run time?

Comment: @SandraRossi The inline declaration "DATA(LV_DESKTOP)" is not possible in this position.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use an inline declaration with the parameters of type `CHANGING` and `EXPORTING` in method calls.

The [ABAP documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abapcall_method_parameters.htm) doesn't say it explicitly, but mentions explicitly that inline declaration can be used for parameters of type `IMPORTING` and `RECEIVING`, with some limitations, without saying anything about the two other types.

There was extensive discussions [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2013/05/27/abap-news-for-release-740-constructor-operators-conv-and-cast/#comment-345872) and [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2013/05/23/abap-news-for-release-740-inline-declarations/#comment-349588).

Examples of possible inline declarations with method calls:

```
cl_gui_frontend_services=>FILE_GET_ATTRIBUTES
    EXPORTING
      filename = `C:\test.txt`
    IMPORTING
      readonly = DATA(readonly) ).
cl_ixml=>create(
    RECEIVING
      rval = DATA(ixml) ).
```

Concerning `EXPORTING` or `CHANGING`, you have to deal with the old declarations. Example:

```
DATA lv_desktop TYPE string.
cl_gui_frontend_services=>get_desktop_directory(
    CHANGING
      desktop_directory = lv_desktop ).
```

Comment: Thank you so much as usual! You are the best!